Начал делать переключение между формами, стал выдавать ошибку "для нестатического поля, метода или свойства Control.show() требует ссылку на объект"
    This.Hide();
    Form level = new form2();
    Form2.Show(); 'ошибка на 
    этой строке'


Когда вставил ссылку выдало новую ошибку "Аргумент 1:  не удаётся преобразовать из " string" в "System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window"

Form2 это класс. level это экземпляр класса Form2.
Скорее всего вам нужно выполнить:
level.Show();

А еще в C# учитывается регистр. Поэтому form2 и Form2 это разные названия.
